# display div inside loop using next and prev button

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am trying to show each div data using next and prev button. how to do it using jQuery?
These are my codes.

PHP code:

```
<div class="divs">
<?php
  for($i=1; $i<=10;$i++){
  ?><div class="cls<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php echo $i; ?> </div>
  <?php
  }
?>
 </div>
 <a id="next">next</a>
 <a id="prev">prev</a>
```

JavaScript code:

```
$(".divs div").each(function(e) {
        if (e != 0)
            $(this).hide();
    });

    $("#next").click(function(){
        if ($(".divs div:visible").next().length != 0)
            $(".divs div:visible").next().show().prev().hide();
        else {
            $(".divs div:visible").hide();
            $(".divs div:first").show();
        }
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: I would probably use removeClass() and addClass() to toggle each one and use separately styled classes to show or hide the divs as appropriate.